# Problema al eliminar carpeta en C# .net

Tags: c#

Tengo un problema y creería que es algo muy tonto, pero llevo ya unos días buscando y probando, pero no me ha funcionado bien

Tengo un programa que al ejecutarse debe eliminar la carpeta de Flash player para que otra aplicación en Flash vuelva a cargar los archivos, el proceso parece que funciona, pero la carpeta no se elimina a pesar de que la barra de progreso de borrado si se ejecuta en pantalla... Tengo que dejarles el código para que sea un poco mas entendible y se pueda revisar.

Soy muy nuevo en C#, así que realmente estoy un poco perdido.

```
    Process processById = Process.GetProcessById(Interaction.Shell("RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 8", AppWinStyle.MinimizedFocus, false, -1));
                while (!processById.HasExited)
                {
                    if (!processById.HasExited)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    goto Label0;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                ProjectData.SetProjectError(exception);
                ProjectData.ClearProjectError();
            }
        Label0:
            string str = string.Concat(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("%appdata%\\Macromedia\\Flash Player"));
            if (MyProject.Computer.FileSystem.DirectoryExists(str))
            {
                try
                {
                    enumerator = MyProject.Computer.FileSystem.GetDirectories(str).GetEnumerator();
                    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
                    {
                        string str1 = string.Concat(enumerator.Current, "\\localhost");
                        if (!MyProject.Computer.FileSystem.DirectoryExists(str1))
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                        using (enumerator1)
                        {
                            enumerator1 = MyProject.Computer.FileSystem.GetDirectories(str1).GetEnumerator();
                            while (enumerator1.MoveNext())
                            {
                                string current = enumerator1.Current;
                                nameOfPath = new string[] { current, "\\", this.GetName_OfPath(Environment.CurrentDirectory), "\\", this.loaderFolderName };
                                string str2 = string.Concat(nameOfPath);
                                if (!MyProject.Computer.FileSystem.DirectoryExists(str2))
                                {
                                    continue;
                                }
                                using (enumerator2)
                                {
                                    enumerator2 = MyProject.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(str2).GetEnumerator();
                                    while (enumerator2.MoveNext())
                                    {
                                        string current1 = enumerator2.Current;
                                        string nameOfPath1 = this.GetName_OfPath(current1);
                                        if (!((nameOfPath1.Contains(this.ConstantAKCache) | nameOfPath1.Contains(this.ConstantAKLang)) & nameOfPath1.Contains(this.ExtCacheFiles)))
                                        {
                                            continue;
                                        }
                                        File.Delete(current1);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (enumerator != null)
                    {
                        enumerator.Dispose();
                    }
                }
            }
            str = string.Concat(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ProgramData\\Macromedia\\Flash Player"));
            if (MyProject.Computer.FileSystem.DirectoryExists(str))
            {
                try
                {
                    enumerator3 = MyProject.Computer.FileSystem.GetDirectories(str).GetEnumerator();
                    while (enumerator3.MoveNext())
                    {
                        string str3 = string.Concat(enumerator3.Current, "\\localhost");
                        if (!MyProject.Computer.FileSystem.DirectoryExists(str3))
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                        using (enumerator4)
                        {
                            enumerator4 = MyProject.Computer.FileSystem.GetDirectories(str3).GetEnumerator();
                            while (enumerator4.MoveNext())
                            {
                                string current2 = enumerator4.Current;
                                nameOfPath = new string[] { current2, "\\", this.GetName_OfPath(Environment.CurrentDirectory), "\\", this.loaderFolderName };
                                string str4 = string.Concat(nameOfPath);
                                if (!MyProject.Computer.FileSystem.DirectoryExists(str4))
                                {
                                    continue;
                                }
                                using (enumerator5)
                                {
                                    enumerator5 = MyProject.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(str4).GetEnumerator();
                                    while (enumerator5.MoveNext())
                                    {
                                        string current3 = enumerator5.Current;
                                        string nameOfPath2 = this.GetName_OfPath(current3);
                                        if (!((nameOfPath2.Contains(this.ConstantAKCache) | nameOfPath2.Contains(this.ConstantAKLang)) & nameOfPath2.Contains(this.ExtCacheFiles)))
                                        {
                                            continue;
                                        }
                                        File.Delete(current3);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (enumerator3 != null)
                    {
                        enumerator3.Dispose();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Gracias de antemano!

Comment: porque borraste tu pregunta anterior para preguntar exactamente lo mismo, y que se pierda el seguimiento de los comentarios que te hicieron antes?

Comment: Porque era una pregunta diferente a esta, y estaba mal formulada, incluso era un programa diferente

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo comprobar la ruta del archivo y si este existe puedes hacerlo agregando un:

```
if(File.Exist(path)){

  console.writeline("si existe"); //este mensaje se imprimirá en la consola.

 //Ahora si vamos a eliminar el archivo/directorio(carpeta)

    Directori.delete(path); //para directorios
    File.delete(path); //para archivos

}
```

Comment: Y esto entonces debo agregarlo al principio del código supongo no?

Comment: Debe ir antes del proceso donde el nuevo flash va a cargar los archivos .

Comment: Entiendo, aunque creo que no me funcionará :/, solamente debe borrar la carpeta este programa, porque el otro programa que es un juego crea la carpeta nuevamente , que es lo que necesito je

Comment: Agrega ese codigo y a la variable path agrega la ruta de tu archivo /directorio y listo